# Understanding startup message in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, anaconda

When I start up the Terminal app or iTerm2, I get the following message:

```
CommandNotFoundError: 'activate is not a conda command.
Did you mean 'source activate'?
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I also have the following `.bash` files:

```
adamg:~ adamg$ ls -a .bash*
.bash_aliases
.bash_history
.bash_profile
.bash_profile-anaconda.bak
.bash_profile-miniconda2.bak
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-02-12_at_19:11:16
.bash_profile.pysave
.bashrc
```

Are the contents of one of these files causing the issue?

**ADDED**:

After running `grep -rn '.' -e 'conda.sh'`

```
adamg:~ adamg$ grep -rn '.' -e 'conda.sh'
./anaconda/bin/compile_et:5:DIR=/Users/adamg/anaconda/share/et
./anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/show.py:6:    anaconda show continuumio
./anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/show.py:7:    anaconda show continuumio/python
./anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/show.py:8:    anaconda show continuumio/python/2.7.5
./anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/show.py:9:    anaconda show sean/meta/1.2.0/meta.tar.gz
Binary file ./anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/search.pyc matches
./anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/remove.py:55:
```

Comment: do this command from your home directory: `grep -rn '.' -e 'conda.sh'`. Please add the output to your question

Comment: Also, do you actually have miniconda2 installed under your account, and if so where is it?

Comment: I'm still running the grep command, as it seems to be taking a while. I had installed miniconda in the past, but (I thought) I had uninstalled it.

Comment: I added the first handful of lines from the grep command. It is still running but returning lots of "No such file or directory"

Comment: Actually, ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc are probably the ones that matter -- what do they have relating to conda? BTW, my guess is that the problem is that miniconda isn't *completely* uninstalled, and one or both of the shell init files are still trying to set it up.

Comment: How would I go about making sure miniconda is completely uninstalled?

Comment: Also, I removed a line from my .bash_profile about miniconda, and it took care of the issue. I think the error was because I *did* completely uninstall miniconda, but still had a reference to it in my bash startup file.

Comment: @Adam_G, that is likely the reason. Most people having this sort of error do not have as many files in their home directory as you did (because conda is usually one of the first things people install), so for them the `grep` command would have been fast and would have told us which file (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or something in `/etc/`) was causing your conda sourcing. Good job solving the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Should I clean up all of the `.bash` files, in some manner?